# Knowledge Article Suggestions: behavior differs between Classic and Lightning

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I'm working on a solution that's expected to be entirely declarative. The objective is to deterministically surface one or more Knowledge articles as suggestions in the Knowledge component, based upon the combination of two specific fields (Customer Number and Case Reason). The suggestion needs to be visible upon Case load, with no user interaction, and needs to update when the Case is edited.

I need the solution to work in Classic Service Console, but I want to preserve Lightning Experience compatibility for a future migration.

### First Attempt

My first stab at this is to utilize article suggestions.

I've done the following:

- Activated Lightning Knowledge.
- Added a formula field to Case to concatenate the two fields mentioned above
- In Knowledge Settings, activated "Suggest related articles on cases" and selected only the formula field mentioned above as a suggestion source.

What I observe is that the suggestions provided in Lightning are as desired: when the Case is edited, the top suggested result is always the Knowledge article whose title matches the formula field.

[image]

In Classic Service Console, however, Salesforce seems to key its suggestions on other criteria, such as the newness of the article and how many views it has received. I obtain a different (and larger) set of suggestions, and the top suggested result is often *not* the Knowledge article whose title matches the formula field.

[image]

(Note that here, I've actually changed the value of the Case Reason field relative to when the Lightning screenshot was taken - the top two results shown here in Classic are ordered incorrectly, and several irrelevant results are included).

### Questions

- Is there anything I can do to influence this search behavior, or am I barking up the wrong tree?
- Alternately, is there a different way to apply Knowledge that might serve my objective better, rather than using search suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the lightning mode "Knowledge One" component is used and that's why "Knowledge One" component is showing at your first picture.

In the second picture, you are using primitive version of Article Management and *NOT* "Knowledge One" component.

Here is the steps to add "Knowledge One" component in the page layout, which is tricky:

1. In the Case Page Layout, click on "Layout Properties" and make sure "Knowledge Sidebar" is **deselected**.

[image: Layout Properties]

2. Then click on Custom Console Components and open the window and configure Knowledge One component in Subtab Components

[image: Custom Console Components]

3. Now, the case record in console you will see the Knowledge One in the Sidebar which is same as your first picture in question.

[image: Knowledge One]

*Hopefully, it will work for you, though I have not configured any formula fields as per your use case for my testing.*

Comment: It works great, Santanu, including with the use of a formula field to drive suggestions in Knowledge One. Thank you for clarifying this for me!

Comment: Follow-up: it works as you say, and is 90% of what I need - the ordering of results is still sometimes not deterministically driven by the formula field, but it's really close, and I'll make a business case to deal with it.